# Building a soundcloud type audio player

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audio, waveform

Basically i'm attempting to build a Web App that is similar to soundcloud but varying in function. I would like the player to load just as soundcloud does, multiple song files loading on one page etc.

I'm currently using Rails 4 and I have most of the app completed but I am really struggling on the audio player. I have looked through some of the popular ones i.e. jPlayer and SoundManager2 however I dont see how I can style these.

I'm really just looking for resources where I can learn more about building an audio player using JS, Web Audio-API or whatever techniques I can use.

Can someone point me in the right direction to some tutorials or code examples of how to start with this project or even what to learn? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of Codecademy tutorials on Deezer and Soundcloud APIs. Maybe not exactly what you're looking for in terms of custom, but they may give you a better idea of what you want to do ultimately.

Deezer: https://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/deezer

Soundcloud: https://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/soundcloud